# Change the legend coloring in ggplot2 with geom_areas only

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following ggplot object:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(3, 15)), aes(x)) + 
  geom_area(aes(color = "Gruppe A"), stat = "function", fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 10, sd = 2), fill = "blue", alpha=.5, xlim = c(3, 15)) +
  geom_area(aes(color = "Gruppe B"), stat = "function", fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 9, sd = 2), fill = "red", alpha=.5, xlim = c(3, 15)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Name", labels = c("Gruppe A", "Gruppe B")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("Gruppe A"="blue", "Gruppe B"="red")) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Note", breaks = c(3:15), limits = c(3, 15)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Dichte")
```

I tried to add a legend manually by adding scale_color_manual. However, the legend fill color does not match the colors of the geom_area layers. How can I configure this fill color manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, but your code needs some additional tweaking:

Specify also the `fill`-color inside the `aes`-call. You can then use `scale_fill_manual` to specify the colors for filling. As you have the same color for filling and for the outside bound you can specify `aesthetics = c("color", "fill")` to apply it to both aesthetics.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(3, 15)), aes(x)) + 
  geom_area(aes(color = "Gruppe A", fill = "Gruppe A"), stat = "function", fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 10, sd = 2), alpha=.5, xlim = c(3, 15)) +
  geom_area(aes(color = "Gruppe B", fill = "Gruppe B"), stat = "function", fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 9, sd = 2), alpha=.5, xlim = c(3, 15)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Name", values = c("Gruppe A" = "blue", "Gruppe B" = "red"), aesthetics = c("color", "fill")) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Note", breaks = c(3:15), limits = c(3, 15)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Dichte")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This worked perfectly. Is there some way to also add the alpha to the legend fill?

Comment: Yes, you could for example add `guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 0.25)))`.